# EV3 brick unable to connect to EV3 Classroom v1.5 app

Tags: ev3

From Google Translate:

My EV3 brick cannot connect to the EV3 classroom version 1.5 application, nor by cable, bluetooth or wifi. I haven't found a way to update the EV3 Brick from this app. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

---

Original text:

> Ma brique EV3 ne peut pas se connecter à l'application EV3 classroom
> version 1.5, ni par câble, bluetooth ou wifi. Je n'ai pas trouvé le
> moyen de faire la mise à jour de la brique EV3 à partir de cette
> application. Comment je peux régler ce problème? Merci.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Here we use English as primary language for communication, so I have edited your questions to help others understand it and have an option to help you out.

Comment: What operating system and version are you using?